# Mutually dependent variables in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vba

Assume I have an input variable `x` and three parameters `a,b,c` such that:

- Given `b` we have `c = f(x,a,b)` for some (known) function `f`
- Given `c` we have `b = g(x,a,c)` for some (known, different) function `g`.

I want to model this in a spreadsheet (Excel for instance). More precisely, if the user provides `x,a` and `b` then `c` will be evaluated and if `c` is given then `b` will be evaluated. It seems like this cannot be achieved directly, since a cell can hold *either* a value *or* a formula.

Is there a **canonical** way to do this? If not, what would be a best-practice workaround (probably some VBA magic)?

Comment: @pnuts: No. Can it be used "interactively"?

Comment: not sure what you mean by [canonical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical) - there is usually no standard way to solve non-standard problems and there is even less standardization about how to solve problems in Excel

Answer (score 1):

You can separate input fields from the calculated values and add some validation that only one of the mutually exclusive field is used, e.g.:

[image]

in my example, I used following conditional formatting to highlight invalid input:

```
=AND($B$4<>"", $B$5<>"")
```

and I used following the formulas for calculated values:

```
=B2
=B3
=IF(AND($B$4<>"", $B$5<>""), "#ERROR: only 1 value can be specified",
    IF($B$4<>"", $B$4, $B$5-1))
=IF(AND($B$4<>"", $B$5<>""), "#ERROR: only 1 value can be specified",
    IF($B$5<>"", $B$5, $B$4+1))
```

more generally:

```
=if(error_condition, error_message, if(b_is_not_empty, b, g(x,a,c)))
```